# Cannot bind Icon property in NavigationView MenuItemTemplate

Tags: .net, mvvm, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've tried to use a `NavigationView` because it looks very useful, but I'm struggling to make it work with the MVVM pattern.

I've attached the MenuItemsSource property like in this snippet:

```
<Page x:Class="App5.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:App5"
      ...>

    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <NavigationView MenuItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
    </NavigationView>
</Page>
```

All I get is this:

[image]

That's cool, but `NavigationViewItem` has a `Icon` property to decorate the text with it.

**How do I set the icon depending on the item bound to each `NavigationViewItem`?**

**NOTICE:** I really don't want to manually add the icon as part of the `MenuItemTemplate` because it's not the way it's supposed to be. What I need is to BIND the Icon property of the implicitly generated `NavigationViewItems`.

The question is how?

I've tried with this (using the `MenuItemContainerStyle`), but it doesn't work:

```
<NavigationView MenuItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <NavigationView.MenuItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItemToIconConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </NavigationView.MenuItemContainerStyle>
    <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
</NavigationView>
```

**NOTE:** With the XAML suggested in the answer below (putting a `NavigationViewItem` inside the `DataTemplate`), the `NavigationViewItem` is duplicated in the visual tree (one nested into another):

[image]

It's not a solution. Moreover, it looks and behaved badly. Take a look to this snapshot of the suggested solution:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was driving me mad! Sadly, it seems the default behaviour is that the contents of `MenuItemTemplate` are placed inside the `NavigationViewItem`'s `ContentPresenter`.

The way I got around this was to copy the relevant part of the default style for `NavigationViewItem`, and modify it slightly:

```
<NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Height="40"
              Margin="-16,0,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Viewbox Grid.Column="0"
                     Margin="16,12">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind Icon}" />
            </Viewbox>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind Name}"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
```

The modification has included setting negative margin for the `Grid` and adding the two `Grid.Column` properties.

I've opened [an issue on the Docs GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/343) so hopefully they will explain the behaviour better.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you dont want to *manually add the icon as part of the `MenuItemTemplate` because it's not the way it's thought to be* (which is absolutely correct), yet you actually do the exact same thing for setting the menu item's text (manually adding a `TextBlock` instead of setting the menu item's `Content` property).

The `TextBlock` overrides any `NavigationItemView` that is automatically created, so there is no icon element to be displayed (a `TextBlock` only contains text, no icon).

Try to simply use a `NavigationViewItem` as template:

```
<NavigationView MenuItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="{Binding Icon}" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: I second this approach, use NavigationViewMenuItem like he does. If you also plan on using separators, you can use a TemplateSelector and swap out the DataTemplate depending on whether you need a MenuItem or Separator

Comment: Sorry, but this approach is a simplistic solution. What is does is to create a `NavigationViewItem` inside a `NavigationViewItem`. Try it and observe the effect: hover the mouse and click it. If your PC is using Fluent Design, you will appreciate the duplication.

Comment: I need to access the implicit `NavigationViewItem`, the one that is generated automatically by the `ContainerGenerator`. The only way I can think of is settings a Style in the `MenuItemContainerStyle`. But I think Bindings aren't supported inside `Styles`.

Comment: While I'm afraid I cannot reproduce your visual problems with the duplicate `NavigationViewItem`, research shows it is indeed not recommended to nest `NavigationViewItem`s (sorry for giving that advice in the first place), however the official solutions seems to "manually" specify icon and text: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f377eb4-f9e6-4997-8ee4-520ea89eab28/rs31709uwp-xaml-how-to-use-navigationviewitem-in-datatemplate?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Note, in 1809 with 17763 SDK, you could indeed use a NavigationViewItem within the data template. 
Down versions, however, only allowed NavigationViewItem within the Navigation view's MenuItems property (not MenuItemTemplate).